# Client side module can not access dependent module when using webpack

Tags: javascript, d3.js, webpack, techan.js

I migrated my project to Webpack.
What it looked like before:

HTML:

```
...
<script src="d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="techan.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
...
```

Which `main.js` is dependent on `techan.js` and `d3.v4.js`. `thechan.js` is dependent on `d3.v4.js`.

After migrating to webpack:

HTML:

```
<script src="dist/main.js"></script>
```

`main.js`:

```
import d3 from './d3.v4.min'
import techan from './techan'
...
```

Now `techan.js` do not recognize `d3`. It is expecting a global variable with the name of `d3` and throws this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'min' of undefined
```

At this line:

```
require('./heikinashi')(indicatorMixin, accessor.ohlc, d3.min, d3.max),
```

How I can fix this issue without touching `techan.js` and `d3.v4.js` code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `main.js` to:

```
window.d3 = require('./d3.v4.min');
window.techan = require('./techan');
...
```

It is fixed now!

Comment: I have the same error but I don't understand your fix.  Paths that start with a './' means a local file in your project, not in the node_modules library.  Are you saying you extracted the d3 and techan js files and put them in your project path?  I added window.d3 = require(d3.min);
window.techan = require('techan');
But it did nothing.

Comment: What is main.js?  I also added     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      // d3: "d3", // if you add this line you can remove the import in the code
      "window.d3": "d3" // this adds d3 in the window object for techan
    })
in the webpack.config.js file as I read in another post.  But it did nothing.